# Filtering a report in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am having an issue trying to filter a report which I have embedded in a form.  I am using an option box which simply should allow the user to view (1) open items or (2) all items.  Unfortuntaely the field on the report which I named "txtStatus" is not being recognised by my filter.  Upon selecting the option button, the a pop up window emerges asking me to enter a value for "txtStatus"

```
The code i have written is as follows:

Private Sub OpzioniFiltro_AfterUpdate()
    If opzioniFiltro = 1 Then
        Me.Filter = "txtStatus<>'closed'"
        Me.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.FilterOn = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are trying to filter a recordset, but you are using the control name on the form instead of the name of the field that is bound to that control.  Does your database table really have the field named 'txtStatus'?

Comment: Exactly..  Thank you..  I found it...  I had to source the original table where the field comes from..